# Automatically trigger Automator upon copying to clipboard

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, automation

Is it possible to trigger workflow for every copying to clipboard? I want to automatically detect URL in clipboard and pass it to shortener service.

Comment: What research have you done prior to asking? What have you tried so far? -- Having searched Google for e.g. "macos monitor clipboard change" it doesn't look promising because apparently there isn't a _clipboard changed event_ and _polling_ is necessary, and as such I stay away from _code_ that requires setting a _time interval_ and has to run constantly. That said I only looked at five or six of the top hits, so I'd suggest you do some research and see what you can find. BTW **Automator** doesn't have any built-in _actions_ to monitor the clipboard, nor does basic vanilla **AppleScript**.

Comment: Assuming you are cognizant a **URL** exits in what you copied to the clipboard, why not just create a _Service/Quick Action_ or trigger a _script_ via a _keyboard shortcut_ manually immediately after you've copied the **URL**? Yeah, not a totally automated solution, but it would certainly decrease the number of manual steps you are taking presently.

Comment: Instead of using command+c you can create a Service using another shortcut, say command+shift+c. So it will copy, open the browser, paste the link, etc.